# Speed only reaches 150Mbps on a 802.11n 300Mbps network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm using a BR-6424n EDIMAX router that broadcasts at 300Mbps(n).
My laptop is connected to my home network with its Realtek RTL8191SE, I searched the internet and found information saying it should have no problem to get up to the 300Mbps speed.

However, it only gets half of the speed(150Mbps).  I've managed to connect the network and get the full speed via a USB W\L device, so the problem is not with the router but with the computer only.

This is on a Toshiba L650-10H laptop with Windows 7 premium x64

Answer (score 5):

Wireless network speeds in that context are an upper limit, not the expected speed.

Comment: So what do i need to do to get that speed? - from what I understand a300mb speed is work with a channel bonding mode.. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @mzE: Probably you'll need it to be in the same room at an optimal distance. You'd have to measure signal strength in different configurations. It's not really something you have a good chance at getting

Comment: I'll describe you the situation: Im sitting in the same room with my laptop and my desk PC. theyre both can connect the wifi network. the router gives a 300 mb lan speed. PC gets 300 mb on brand N, and the laptop is getting 150 mb only same brand. like something is blocking it from getting the full speed. maybe it cannot connect to all network channels for some reason... :\\

Comment: @muzE: Your laptop does have an N card right?

Comment: Like I already said- "...Realtek RTL8191SE, I searched the internet and it should have no problem to get the 300mb speed." though it recognize the network as 'gn' from time to time.. but generally just n, which is good

Answer (score 2):

Your Edimax BR-6424n is a 2x2 (2 transmit radio chains, 2 receive radio chains -- sometimes called "2T2R") device, so it can send and receive at up to 300mbps (given 40MHz wide channels).

Unfortunately, your Realtek RTL8191SE is only a 1x2 (1T2R), so it can only transmit at up to 150mbps (again assuming 40MHz wide channels).

Your software that's reporting your Wi-Fi connection speed probably isn't written with asymmetric designs like this in mind, so it's probably just reporting the client-to-AP speed and assuming the AP-to-client speed is similar.

Note that 40MHz wide channels take up too much of the 2.4GHz band, so it's a "good neighbor" policy to only use 20MHz wide channels in 2.4GHz. But in your case that would mean limiting your rates to 72.2 up and 144.4 down.